# Docker Volumes: Docker Volume does not get mounted correctly on Amazon Linux

Tags: docker, ansible

I am currently trying to deploy a docker registry to Amazon ec2 using ansible. The task from my cookbook looks like this:

```
- name: run docker registry container
  docker:
    image: registry
    name: docker-registry
    state: reloaded
    env:
      SETTINGS_FLAVOR: local
      STORAGE_PATH: /opt/docker-registry
      SEARCH_BACKEND: sqlalchemy
    volumes:
    - "/data/docker-registry-server/opt/docker-registry:/opt/docker-registry"
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
```

As you can see the registry is deployed as a container inside docker.
This works to some degree. The container gets started correctly, but the volume does not get mounted correctly. I checked this by running:

```
docker exec -t -i docker-registry touch /opt/docker-registry/touch.me
```

This creates a new file in the container in the folder where the volume should be mounted. So this file should appear on the host in `/data/docker-registry-server/opt/docker-registry` but it does not.

When running `docker inspect docker-registry` I get this result:

```
[{
"AppArmorProfile": "",
"Args": [],
"Config": {
    "AttachStderr": false,
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": false,
    "Cmd": [
        "docker-registry"
    ],
    "CpuShares": 0,
    "Cpuset": "",
    "Domainname": "",
    "Entrypoint": null,
    "Env": [
        "SETTINGS_FLAVOR=local",
        "SEARCH_BACKEND=sqlalchemy",
        "STORAGE_PATH=/opt/docker-registry",
        "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
        "DOCKER_REGISTRY_CONFIG=/docker-registry/config/config_sample.yml"
    ],
    "ExposedPorts": {
        "5000/tcp": {}
    },
    "Hostname": "7d4bb2448234",
    "Image": "registry",
    "MacAddress": "",
    "Memory": 0,
    "MemorySwap": 0,
    "NetworkDisabled": false,
    "OnBuild": null,
    "OpenStdin": false,
    "PortSpecs": null,
    "StdinOnce": false,
    "Tty": false,
    "User": "",
    "Volumes": {
        "/opt/docker-registry": {}
    },
    "WorkingDir": ""
},
"Created": "2015-04-20T14:00:44.547620575Z",
"Driver": "devicemapper",
"ExecDriver": "native-0.2",
"ExecIDs": [
    "5ea0f2a69b5010ee769963ea030dbf5016bef15f50515c120c3e1d27edb64e03",
    "4d7cdbc371bc7bd7eddc73f531fe4e538186556b59b20da74ffa705ab31306c0"
],
"HostConfig": {
    "Binds": [
        "/data/docker-registry-server/opt/docker-registry:/opt/docker-registry:rw"
    ],
    "CapAdd": null,
    "CapDrop": null,
    "ContainerIDFile": "",
    "Devices": null,
    "Dns": null,
    "DnsSearch": null,
    "ExtraHosts": null,
    "IpcMode": "",
    "Links": null,
    "LxcConf": null,
    "NetworkMode": "",
    "PidMode": "",
    "PortBindings": {
        "5000/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "5000"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Privileged": false,
    "PublishAllPorts": false,
    "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
    "RestartPolicy": {
        "MaximumRetryCount": 0,
        "Name": ""
    },
    "SecurityOpt": null,
    "VolumesFrom": null
},
"HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/7d4bb2448234962ba8f9da87d3650b38e608a1e405130ba6b35200f52e07ce5b/hostname",
"HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/7d4bb2448234962ba8f9da87d3650b38e608a1e405130ba6b35200f52e07ce5b/hosts",
"Id": "7d4bb2448234962ba8f9da87d3650b38e608a1e405130ba6b35200f52e07ce5b",
"Image": "59b1f7d49dc843631b9be86f581f9c8a726f7cea8a5c37e648c822e40e440633",
"MountLabel": "",
"Name": "/docker-registry",
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "docker0",
    "Gateway": "172.17.42.1",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.62",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "fe80::42:acff:fe11:3e",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 64,
    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:3e",
    "PortMapping": null,
    "Ports": {
        "5000/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "5000"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"Path": "docker-registry",
"ProcessLabel": "",
"ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/7d4bb2448234962ba8f9da87d3650b38e608a1e405130ba6b35200f52e07ce5b/resolv.conf",
"RestartCount": 0,
"State": {
    "Error": "",
    "ExitCode": 0,
    "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "OOMKilled": false,
    "Paused": false,
    "Pid": 21595,
    "Restarting": false,
    "Running": true,
    "StartedAt": "2015-04-20T14:00:44.791121849Z"
},
"Volumes": {
    "/opt/docker-registry": "/data/docker-registry-server/opt/docker-registry"
},
"VolumesRW": {
    "/opt/docker-registry": true
}
}
]
```

This looks to me like the container itself knows that it should use a volume. The `Volumes` entry lists the correct path. So this is most likely a docker and not an ansible problem.

I am using docker 1.5.0, build a8a31ed/1.5.0

At this point I am convinced there is most likely a stupid mistake in how volumes should be used. (Most likely my fault...)

Can anybody tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the touch worked? Can you see the file inside in the container afterwards?

Comment: @AdrianMouat the file was created in the container. I logged into the container using ```docker exec -t -i docker-registry bash``` and used ``ls`` to take a look.

Comment: Looks like a bug. A lot of people have problems with devicemapper - try aufs or overlay if you can.

Comment: I somehow fixed the problem by moving ```/var/lib/docker/``` from the ec2 instance to an other blockstore. As the ec2 instance and the new blockstore are both using the same volume type (gp2) and filesystem (ext4) I am not sure why that helped.

Comment: Do you have something in `docker events` or `docker logs your_container` when the volume should be mounted?

Comment: @user2915097 not es far es I can tell. As I said I fixed the problem by moving the folder I am mounting.

Comment: I use nfs and it also has same problem, it just create image inside container :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you said that it worked by moving the folder you are mounting, I would check a few things:

- Make sure the directory you are mounting actually exists on the host machine.
- Make sure that whatever user you are running your ansible playbook under has the correct permissions to access the folder you are attempting to mount.